# Menu Item appears on task bar rather than above it

Tags: c#

I am manually adding a notify icon to the task bar of a form based application using c#. The menu is added ok but when I right click the icon the list appears below the task bar as default. How do I  get it to appear in the location you would normally expect?

```
NotifyIcon notfiyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();

            menuItem.Text = "Exit";
            menuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLogOut_Click);

            contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
            contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("hello");
            notfiyIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

            notfiyIcon.Text = "Property Sales";

            Icon icon = new Icon("icon.ico");
            notfiyIcon.Icon = icon;

            notfiyIcon.Visible = true;
```

[image]

This is what where i would like it to appear.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by _below the taskbar_? Can you post a screenshot? Also, what OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the context menu on Windows.

Typically, context menus open downward from the mouse location, which is what you see in your first screenshot.  In your second screenshot, the context menu is too tall to open downwards (it would extend off the screen), so instead, it opens upwards from the mouse location in order to be fully visible.

You could manually set the menu location, but for consistency's sake, it's not recommended.